# Looking to trim a string using javascript / regex

Tags: javascript, regex

I'm looking for some assistance with JavaScript/Regex when trying to format a string of text.
I have the following IDs:

```
00A1234/A12
0A1234/A12
A1234/A12
000A1234/A12
```

I'm looking for a way that I can trim all of these down to `1234/A12`. In essence, it should find the first letter from the left, and remove it and any preceding numbers so the final format should be `0000/A00` or `0000/AA00`.

Is there an efficient way this can be acheived by Javascript? I'm looking at Regex at the moment.

Comment: Try building regex at a site like [regex101.com](http://regex101.com).

Comment: `str.match(/\d{4}\/[A-Z]{1,2}\d{2}/)`?

Comment: `Is there an efficient way` define "efficient".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of focussing on what you want to strip, look at what you want to get:

```
/\d{4}\/[A-Z]{1,2}\d{2}/
```

```js
var str = 'fdfhfjkqhfjAZEA0123/A45GHJqffhdlh';
match = str.match(/\d{4}\/[A-Z]{1,2}\d{2}/);
if (match) console.log(match[0]);
```

Comment: Works perfect trincot, Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

You could seach for leading digits and a following letter.

```js
var data = ['00A1234/A12', '0A1234/A12', 'A1234/A12', '000A1234/A12'],
    regex = /^\d*[a-z]/gi;

data.forEach(s => console.log(s.replace(regex, '')));
```

Or you could use [`String#slice`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/slice) for the last 8 characters.

```js
var data = ['00A1234/A12', '0A1234/A12', 'A1234/A12', '000A1234/A12'];

data.forEach(s => console.log(s.slice(-8)));
```

Comment: More generic `/^\d*[A-Z]/g`

Answer (score 0):

A regex such as this will capture all of your examples, with a numbered capture group for the bit you're interested in

```
[0-9]*[A-Z]([0-9]{4}/[A-Z]{1,2}[0-9]{2})
```

```js
var input = ["00A1234/A12","0A1234/A12","A1234/A12","000A1234/A12"];
var re = new RegExp("[0-9]*[A-Z]([0-9]{4}/[A-Z]{1,2}[0-9]{2})");

input.forEach(function(x){
    console.log(re.exec(x)[1])
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use this function. Using regex find the first letter, then make a substring starting after that index.

```
function getCode(s){
  var firstChar = s.match('[a-zA-Z]');
  return s.substr(s.indexOf(firstChar)+1)
}

getCode("00A1234/A12");
getCode("0A1234/A12");
getCode("A1234/A12");
getCode("000A1234/A12");
```